# R does not recognize the correct libstdc++.so library

Tags: r, libstdc++

When I try to install the `kernlab` package on R 2.15.2 on Scientific Linux 5.5, I get the following error message:

```
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
  unable to load shared object '~/bin/lib64/R/library/kernlab/libs/kernlab.so':
  /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_41/jre/../lib/amd64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by ~/bin/lib64/R/library/kernlab/libs/kernlab.so)
```

R 2.11 is installed on the same system, which installs kernlab just fine. Additionally, the following reports no errors:

```
ldd -r ~/bin/lib64/R/library/kernlab/libs/kernlab.so
```

So it seems that R simply doesn't manage to use the right libraries. I set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/usr/local/gcc-4.6.0/lib64/`, which is where the working version of `libstdc++.so.6` seems to be, but that did not help.

How can it be that R refuses to use the right libraries? And how can I make it use the correct one?

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out?

Answer (score 0):

> How can it be that R refuses to use the right libraries?

Something else in the process must be loading the older `libstdc++.so` before the R shared lib gets loaded.  I'm surprised LD_LIBRARY_PATH doesn't help though.